# How to Edit This

Tags: vim

I'm trying to mod SKyrim and have to edit my batch file.  I need to change each line to look like:

```
Player.GetInFaction "<Faction ID>"  ;;; <Description>
```

E.g. :

```
FACT:  (00000013) 'Creature Faction'
```

would be:

```
Player.GetInFaction "00000013"  ;;; Creature Faction
```

The lines look like this(there are hundreds):

```
FACT:  (00000013) 'Creature Faction' 
FACT:  (000135A0) 'Thalmor Splinter Faction'    
FACT:  (00016C2F) 'Black Briar Meadery Faction'    
FACT:  (00016C30) 'Riften Fishery Faction'
```

So how do I quickly edit them? I downloaded Vim but have no idea how to use it.

Comment: It says: No previous regular experession when I press N

Comment: "*I downloaded Vim but have no idea how to use it.*" This is not an application support forum for vim.

Comment: If you're new to Vim (and its navigation and editing commands), you should spend 30 minutes on the `vimtutor` that comes with it (see `:help vimtutor` inside Vim). Then, there are several good resources, cheatsheets, and vi / Vim tutorials out there on the net. http://vimcasts.org/ has several short entertaining episodes that go beyond the basics.

Answer (score 0):

Press `i` to enter edit mode, then `esc` to exit it. To close vim saving the file just type `:wq` and press `enter`

Comment: But how to  edit one line then make it the same for others?

Comment: @Memo Oh! Now I got it, do you mean something like this https://dab1nmslvvntp.cloudfront.net/wp-content/uploads/2016/05/1464358146matching.gif ??

Comment: @Memo May be you want to check this blog post instead http://scholarslab.org/research-and-development/bulk-editing-in-vim/

Comment: Yes that's right. Thank you. But i have a hard time figuring it out.

Answer (score 0):

First of all @Ingo Karkat is right you need to learn how to use Vim with `:help vimtutor` and http://vimcasts.org/ for example.

Now for your particular use case, press <kbd>:</kbd> to open command line mode and then type the following command:

```
%s/FACT:  (\(.*\)) '\(.*\)'/Player.getInFaction "\1" ;;; \2/
```

This is a substitution command which will match all lines in the following format:

```
FACT:  ([some characters]) '[some characters]'
```

And will replace them by

```
Player.getInFaction "[first group of characters]" ;;; [second group of characters]
```

Remember to use the doc too: [`:h :substitute`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/change.txt.html#%3Asubstitute) will show how to use substitutions and [this question](https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/2136/1841) will show you how to use the doc.